# How edit files with Visual Code remote extension using sudo

Tags: vscode-remote

The Visual Code remote SSH extension allows editing any remote file in the embedded terminal just using `code <filename>` which is super useful.

However when opening a file with sudo e.g. `sudo code /etc/fstabs` it returns

```
sudo: code: command not found
```

Is there any way to allow the use of `code` to any user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible at the time of writing as it would require the underlying `node` which is running [VSCode server](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4a130c40ed876644ed8af2943809d08221375408/src/vs/server/node/server.cli.ts) to be running with `sudo`, which it is not.

I have opened a GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6427).